# Copy files limited to 50GB or so?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, files, copying

Several times I have tried to copy a vhd file from one HDD to another one colocated in the same physical box and connected to the same motherboard.
GUI drag and drop, Powershell, copy and paste - all of these methods stop copying after about 50GB of transferred data.
Are there any data transfer limits?

Answer (score 0):

The file size limit for NTFS5 is about 16 ExaBytes, your files are not that big, because you couldn't store them in the first place.

There is no limit on the copy operation itself and I often copy files bigger than 500GB.

Sounds like a hardware problem to me. Test copying the file within the same HDD or to a different one to find out which drive has the problem.

Comment: Hi @peter :-). It works within the same HDD, but does not to a different HDD.

Comment: @Mipo - it's a problem with your hardware